# Dynamically get parameters from script for jenkins job

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, parameters, pipeline

Im looking for help to get the list of jar's in an artifactory using shell command (something like below) :

curl -s -u 'username:password' https://artifactorypro.jfrog.com/artifactory/abc/com/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ | grep jar |cut -d '"' -f2 | tail -5  .

How do I return the output as parameters to jenkins job ?

If its not good idea , help me with options to pass the snapshot id's using jfrog api or groovy script to list the snapshots . I see multiple plugins supporting groovy but not shell.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, could you try assigning the command to a variable

```
variable=$(curl -s -u 'username:password' https://artifactorypro.jfrog.com/artifactory/abc/com/1.0-SNAPSHOT/ | grep jar |cut -d '"' -f2 | tail -5)
```

And then simply send the variable as a parameter?

Comment: This would result top 5 snapshots and user could pick any one depending on need. This solution might not work.  My motto is to pass the output as parameters for jenkins pipeline job.

Comment: I guess I don't fully understand what you're trying to achieve here. Could you give me an example of what the result of this bash command would look like, and an example of what you want passed in as a parameter for you Jenkins pipeline?